# Default Source for None image?

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting valid uri for image source BUT if I delete images from media file, it will return None file.

I usually check the invalid uri for the Image but this time the server's image directory couldn't render image.

```
if(!_.isNil(item.img)) { // This checks if uri is null or string
```

I tried out defaultSource but it doesn't work; it shows white screen forever

```
<Image
        fadeDuration={0}
        key={item.id}
        source={{uri: item.img}}
        style={styles.rowImage}
        resizeMode="cover"
        defaultSource={require('../../assets/images/styles.png')}
      />
```

How can we place a default image if `Image` from previous valid uri doesn't exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`onError`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#onerror) to handle if your uri doesn't exist. Then use `setNativeProps` to replace your image by the image you want.

**Example**

Using local path:

```
import resolveAssetSource from 'resolveAssetSource';

...

handleErr(item){

   var imgsrc = require('imagePathHere');

   this.refs[`testimage-${item}`].setNativeProps({
      src: [resolveAssetSource(imgsrc)] //use source for ios instead of src
   });

}

...

<Image
        //ref="testimage"
        ref={`testimage-${item.id}`}
        fadeDuration={0}
        key={item.id}
        source={{uri: item.img}}
        style={styles.rowImage}
        resizeMode="cover"
        defaultSource={require('../../assets/images/styles.png')}
        onError={() => this.handleErr(item.id)}
      />
```

Or use from url:

```
handleErr(item){

   var imgsrc = 'http://blahblah.com/tes.jpg';

   this.refs[`testimage-${item}`].setNativeProps({
      src: [{uri: imgsrc}] //use source for ios instead of src
   });

}

...

<Image
        //ref="testimage"
        ref={`testimage-${item.id}`}
        fadeDuration={0}
        key={item.id}
        source={{uri: item.img}}
        style={styles.rowImage}
        resizeMode="cover"
        defaultSource={require('../../assets/images/styles.png')}
        onError={() => this.handleErr(item.id)}
      />
```

Comment: Can we try to avoid using `ref`??? I usually have more than 20 images in a row and it's impossible use `ref` to all of them

Comment: Please see updated answer, I assume that you use map to generate your images by json

Comment: @DennisFrea what does resolveAssetSource means? Is that a component or package?